# How to disable OpenVPN Connect from running at startup on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, openvpn

I'm using OpenVPN Connect 2.6.0.100 and I want to prevent it from starting on windows startup. I've disabled it first from Startup in TaskManager, but it doesn't helped, so I removed it from Starup folder as well, but it doesn't helped either. Any idea what can I try next?

Comment: Have you tried going to services (services.msc) and changing the startup to 'manual'?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what moron coded this and thought this automatic startup was a good idea WITHOUT ME EXPLICITLY ASKING FOR IT - and making it so difficult to turn off, however - for one - *even* if you make the two services in `services.msc`, "OpenVPN Interactive Service" and "OpenVPNService", of type "Manual":

[image: services]

... then OpenVPN GUI Connect will STILL start at startup, except it will also complain that services aren't started.

Apparently the answer is here:

[Windows 10 Disable OpenVPN startup for new Users - OpenVPN Support Forum](https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=31224)

> Just reinstall and disable this item
>
> [image: openvpn installer]

Oh, btw, if you *do* run the .msi installer again in Windows 10, note that "Modify" will have a greyed out button, so you cannot really use it:

[image: greyed out]

... so you really have to uninstall and reinstall.

I really hope one day, an unattended update messes up all nuclear plants in the world, so all of the computers, programs and this damn world all go to hell.